# How can I add color to a certain row in a CSV table in restructured text?

Tags: row, background-color, restructuredtext

I have this table defined in a .rst file:

> .. csv-table:: Supported Platforms

> :file: ./supported_platforms.csv

> :header-rows: 1

> :width: 100%

> :widths: 5 15 5 15 15 5 5 5 5 5 6

> :align: left

> :class: longtable

I want to add color to one of the rows, preferably without adding CSS code.
I have not tried anything, no idea how to do it.

Comment: I don't think "preferably without adding CSS code" is feasible.

Comment: There is no provision for text or background color in standard reStructuredText. The rationale is the division of semantics and style. You will need custom CSS to select a row and color it.